# Matplotlib maskoceans results using lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have 3 lists x,y,z containing long,lat,value. I am trying to construct a plot using contourf and maskoceans. The result i am getting isn't very good near the coastline. Trying to increase arguments of linspace leads to memory error. Is there a way to achieve better result close to the coastline? 
My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap,maskoceans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[23.027008, 22.774524, 23.010211, 22.346053, 21.264416, 21.261967, 21.31769, 21.478437, 21.406678, 21.453064]
y=[36.547227, 36.824754, 37.482874, 37.61182, 37.873769, 37.935473, 37.978032, 38.139038, 38.162707, 38.168772]
z=[155.15, 354.86, 400.2, 47.16, 188.44, 277.01, 375.12, 87.71, 133.85, 123.56]

map =Basemap(projection='mill',
             llcrnrlat=36.928942,llcrnrlon=21.696255,
             urcrnrlat=38.03002,urcrnrlon=23.497298,
             resolution='i')
map.drawcoastlines()

xi, yi = np.linspace(21,24, 100), np.linspace(36, 39, 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

xm,ym=map(xi,yi)

rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)

zm=maskoceans(xi,yi,zi,resolution='h',grid=1.25)
map.contourf(xm, ym, zm,cmap='jet')
map.colorbar()


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is your interpolated grid is not fine enough for the intricacies of the coastline, since you are quite zoomed in. Plus you are using a different resolution for your oceans as for your basemap which causes some strange artifacts. So I made 3 changes to your code:

- Don't use `map` as a variable name - it is a built-in Python function and shouldn't be overridden.

  `m = Basemap(...`
- Increase the resolution of your interpolated grid

  `xi, yi = np.linspace(21,24, 1000), np.linspace(36, 39, 1000)`
- Match resolution of the maskoceans with the Basemap

  `zm=maskoceans(xi,yi,zi,resolution='i',grid=1.25)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But with the limititations of stackoverflow (doesn't allow files to be uploaded) the question wasn't clear enough. because it was simplified. Actually i am using python (pypyodbc) to connect to a small database in order to obtain values. Usually it fetches around 600 rows of longs,lats,values depending on the query. I can't increase linspace argument not even to 300 without running out of memory.The other two suggestions/corrections were applied of course

Comment: Ah, OK, I'm afraid I'm not sure how to solve that and not sure there is much more that could be done to get better resolution around the coastlines. Another option may be to lower the resolution of the coastlines? Hard to tell without knowing intricacies of your problem. If you are having memory issues might be worth opening another question with some details to see if someone can help.